# Instrumenting User interface click Actions/Event Handler

Tags: javascript, html, performance, knockout.js, instrumentation

I am trying to find out different ways using which we can instrument click action in Knockoutjs and place any code for instrumentation. I am primarily looking to instrument the time taken for the click action handlers.

**What i have tried ?**

I have tried to hook into bindings using the **Preprocess** function available on the binding handlers. I can hook into Knockout’s logic for interpreting data-bind attributes by providing a binding preprocessor for a specific binding handle.

So, i modify the function reference to add the interception code. Apparently, adding code **before** and **after** the function call. Following code shows a working version of the concept.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.click.preprocess = function(value, name, addBindingCallback) {
           if (value.indexOf("function") > -1) {
              
                modifiedvalue = value.replace("function", "function __placeholderAnonymousFunction");
                // return value needs to be returned back, so that event bubble/Capture can be done correctly 
                modifiedvalue = modifiedvalue + "; var returnValue = __placeholderAnonymousFunction.apply($data, arguments); ";
            } else {
                // return value needs to be returned back, so that event bubble/Capture can be done correctly 
                modifiedvalue = "var returnValue = " + value + ".apply($data, arguments);";
            }

            var returnvalue = "function($data,$event){ " +
                "InterceptStart();"+
        modifiedvalue +
                " ;InterceptEnd(); " +
                " return returnValue;" +
                " }";

            return returnvalue;
        }

var startTime;
var endTime;

function InterceptStart(){
  startTime = performance.now();
 console.log("start");
}

function InterceptEnd(){
  endTime = performance.now();
 console.log("end. Total time spent=" + (endTime - startTime));
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.clickHandler = function() {
        console.log("in Click handler");
    };
    return self;
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind='click: clickHandler'>Intercept Me</button>
```

**Questions**

1. Do you see any possible issues with above code. It handles the scenario where the click handler can be a function reference, anonymous function, function called with bind, apply. Would it fail in any other scenarios ?
2. For the scenario where code in handler updates any UI element or updates any observable which is binded to HTML, is it possible to hook into any of the available functions in knockoutjs or javascript which i can call after the UI update is done. *The intent is to capture the time it took Event Handler + UI updation. Basically, capturing the time for scripting + render + Paint after a click action is done.* Should i add code in `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` so that the code is executed at the end of the paint. Something similar to `afterRender` in knockout Component Bindings.
3. Are there any other **recommended** approaches available for this kind of use case?

**Note:** For click handlers involving XHR interactions, i am hooking onto the XMLHttpRequest and i already have the code for that. Therefore, XHR interactions are out of scope for this question.

**EDIT 1:**  I am not looking for Debugging solutions. This is for instrumenting the function calls and sending the data to another application.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other **recommended** approaches available for this kind of use case?

My recommended approach is to use your browser's developer tools... They give you exactly what you want: time spent in scripting (event handler), layout and paints.

For example: (recorded on a [knockout documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html))

- The yellow parts shows the scripting time. Notice the `Run Microtasks` which comes from a `deferred` update (I don't think your current code accounts for those...)
- The purple parts are your layout & style updates
- The green part is where the updated UI is painted

[image: A performance overview of a click handler]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am aware of the developer tools and the purpose is not debugging but the data need to be sent to the analytics solution.